Catch Error in a SQL Server Logon Trigger
I have written a Logon trigger in a SQL Server to control logon authorization.
ALTER TRIGGER [LOG_TRG_01]
ON ALL SERVER WITH EXECUTE AS 'SA'
FOR LOGON
AS

BEGIN

if ORIGINAL_LOGIN() = 'sa'
begin
return;
end;

if ORIGINAL_LOGIN() = 'OMEGACAEVDEV1'
begin
-- not allowed to logon
rollback;
end;

-- Insert Trail
EXEC [OmegaCoreAudit].[OMEGACA].[P_ACC_UNF_TRAIL]
0, 'trail_details', 'ip', 'server', 'db', 0 ;

END 
GO

It does (as expected):

OMEGACAEVDEV1 is not allowed to logon
OMEGACAEVDEV2 is allowed to logon
An audit event is inserted by proc P_ACC_UNF_TRAIL in a table for both users.

All three above I want to stay this way !
But I need to have error handling in it, so that in case of whatever error the login is allowed to login - but keeping a record on another table named SYS_ERROR_LOG (with error details).
In this trigger I have intentionally provoked an error by "select 10/0"
The new trigger is:
ALTER TRIGGER [LOG_TRG_02]
ON ALL SERVER WITH EXECUTE AS 'SA'
FOR LOGON
AS

BEGIN

BEGIN TRY

if ORIGINAL_LOGIN() = 'sa'
begin
return;
end;

--provoke error
select 10/0;

if ORIGINAL_LOGIN() = 'OMEGACAEVDEV1'
begin
-- not allowed to logon
rollback;
end;

-- Insert Trail
EXEC [OmegaCoreAudit].[OMEGACA].[P_ACC_UNF_TRAIL]
0, 'trail_details', 'ip', 'server', 'db', 0 ;

END TRY

BEGIN CATCH

Insert into OmegaCoreAudit.OMEGACA.SYS_ERROR_LOG 
([LOGIN_USER_NAME], [DB_USER_NAME], [USERHOST], [IP_ADDRESS], [OS_USER], [BG_JOB_ID], [ERROR_DATA])
values
('LOGIN_NAME', 'USER_NAME', 'USER_HOST', 'IP', NULL, NULL, 'ERROR_MESSAGE'); 

END CATCH

END 
GO

Ps. the above code "if ORIGINAL_LOGIN() = 'OMEGACAEVDEV1'" represents a simplified version of a wider authorization process.
Problem:
CATCH is not working.
Both users are not allowed to logon ("Logon failed for login '[user]' due to trigger execution")
No record is written on table SYS_ERROR_LOG. I was expecting one for each user.
What can I do to fix this problem?
best regards
Altin

This code makes no sense, if you try catch, then the RAISERROR will be caught too

Why handle this on a trigger at all? If you don't want a LOGIN to work, then delete or disable it. This feels like an XY Problem.

If you want to block a login you can just remove permissions to CONNECT. If you want to track logons use XEvents. Why use  a logon trigger? Why would you get an unintended error in a logon trigger? How about you show us what you are actually trying to achieve, and what error is actually going on?

Thank You   Thom A and  Charlieface
I edit the question, added:
"PS.  the above code "if ORIGINAL_LOGIN() = 'OMEGACAEVDEV1'" represent a simplified version of a wider authorization process."
Authorization is more complex then just username. The logon trigger is needed because under certain circumstances I want to disable login, and allow on some others.

I'm not sure try catch and implicit transactions works well together, while I can't test it, I'm guessing the real error becomes that you can't write data to the log due to transaction being in bad state. This is probably solvable, but I'd still suggest not doing try catch handling and just error out. Noone is doing these kind of pinpoint audits, unless you're on oracle

IMHO doing rollback/commit in a trigger (or even in a stored proc) is not a good idea. Better to throw and let the caller handle the transaction

as a sidenote, does the concept of indentation means anything to you ? Why not make your code a bit more readable.

Thank You siggemannen
I need to catch the error because if I don't no user will be allowed to logon. My logic is that in case of any eventual error in the logon trigger, the user shall be allowed to logon and a log is kept with details on sys_error_log.
You are right about Oracle, I have already done this thing in Oracle. There the concept of Autonomous Transaction helped me, while with SQL Server I am suffering.

Hi GuidoG.
On its own docs SQL Server uses a ROLLBACK on a logon trigger to disallow a logon under user-defined circumstances:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/logon-triggers?view=sql-server-ver16
"make your code a bit more readable" - I tried to present this a simple as I could.

Honestly would not rely on Microsoft docs for examples, a lot of them are very poor.  That example instead of ROLLBACK should have had THROW ... which would have had the same effect and also given a proper error message to the user. How about you show us what your "wider authorization process" is, because we're not really understanding what this code is supposed to do. Why not throw an error outside the catch?

Hi  Charlieface
Did use: "THROW 51000, 'not allowed to logo', 1;" ... instead of RAISERROR and Rollback. All is the same.

Same as what? I haven't seen the issue yet. If you have --provoke error select 10/0; in your code then take it out, why would you want to provole an error? If that's a placeholder for another issue then please show what's actually happening. It's really not clear what's going on.

Hi Charlieface
I have provoked the error because I want to have error handling in my trigger. Errors do happen sooner or later.
And in this case the problem is that CATCH does not work.
The Title of this question could well be: "TRY Catch not working in a SQL Server logon trigger"
